# Image with stretch vertical alignment inside a ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When I have an Image with `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` inside a container such as a HubSection, the Image expands perfectly from top to bottom in my page. I.e.:

```
<HubSection>
  <DataTemplate>
      <Image
        Loaded="BigPic_Loaded"
        ImageFailed="BigPic_ImageFailed"
        x:Name="BigPic"
        Source="http://i.imgur.com/hd4tFk0.jpg"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Then, I want to be able to zoom into the image, for that purpose I am adding a ScrollViewer around the Image. Then, the `VerticalAlignment='Stretch'` does not work as I expect, the Height of the Image does not match the Height of the page anymore. I.e.:

```
<HubSection>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ScrollViewer
      ZoomMode="Enabled"
      HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      MinZoomFactor="1"
      MaxZoomFactor="4">
      <Image
        Loaded="BigPic_Loaded"
        ImageFailed="BigPic_ImageFailed"
        x:Name="BigPic"
        Source="http://i.imgur.com/hd4tFk0.jpg"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </ScrollViewer>
  </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Is there any fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to handle the `SizeChanged` event of your `ScrollViewer` and set the size of the BigPic to the size of the `ScrollViewer`.